# How to enable pull refresh in a modern toolkit app

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

When an application is created using Ext.application() (modern toolkit), pull-to-refresh functionality seems to be disabled on the mobile browsers. Is there any way to re-enable it?

Code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        //Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Title',
            html: 'content'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share some code, probably a fiddle (fiddle.sencha.com)? Did you use the plugin 'pullrefresh'. in Cordova or simple browser. any specific device? We got it working.

Comment: There is nothing special about it. 
It is a basic starter example. I edited te original question to include the code.

The fiddle is at: https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3j4i (but it is not an appropriate test place).

When i run the example code in a mobile browser (Chrome, Samsung Internet) under Android - the pull down to refresh is not working

Comment: Another example will be the the starter template app generated with Sencha Cmd (sencha generate app ..). It also prevents pull refresh for both classic and modern toolkit versions

Comment: can you post which Sencha CMD you are using?

Comment: version is 7.5.1.20

Comment: If I run your fiddle pull refresh works for me. Tested on Safari / Chrome with iOS 15.3.1 and Samsung Internet / Chrome with Samsung Galaxy A12 Android 11.

Comment: It is running on the fiddle, of course - that is why i told in my previous comment it is not the appropriate test case. The fiddle page is lot different than a 'clean' application, because it 'contains' the application within. Can you try the following - it is a simple starter app generated using sencha command - without any modifications: http://extjs-bg.com:88/test/?

I thinks this is a styling-related behavior...

Comment: @MXStarter I see, it is not working. Try to setup the main view as viewport, for example defining like `Ext-define('MyMainView', {extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport', ....`. Also check if your `index.html` has something like: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Yes, my my meta setting is '<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />'. Without it, the elements are very small on the screen so it must be present, i believe. Also, in the version generated by Sencha CMD it is: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">

Comment: So please try to extend the main view from `Ext.container.Viewport`, and see if it helps.

Comment: Not sure if i understood you. So just to be sure - in my example, i have 2 components - 1. An automatically created `Ext.Viewport` (singleton instantiated by `Ext.application()`), 2. A panel within the viewport. What you understand under "main view" - the viewport or the panel? Should i destroy the Ext.Viewport instance and replace it with `Ext.container.Viewport` instance? But even then - i'm confused, because there is no `Ext.container.Viewport` class in the modern toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem described comes from the Ext.Viewport instance and more precisely - the modifications it makes to the styling of the body element. If i skip the 'normal' app launch process (for example - rendering the initial view directly on the body and return before `Ext.application()` call which creates the viewport) - it works as expected:

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'Panel',
        html: 'My panel text...'
    });
        return;
        Ext.application({...});
});
```